# Is it necessary to enqueue read/write when using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

Assume that I am `wait()`ing for the kernel to compute the work.

I was wondering if, when allocating a buffer using the CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag, it is necessary to use enqueueRead/Write on the buffer, or they can *always* be omitted?

**Note**

I am aware of this note on the reference:

> Calling clEnqueueReadBuffer to read a region of the buffer object with
>   the ptr argument value set to host_ptr + offset, where host_ptr is a
>   pointer to the memory region specified when the buffer object being
>   read is created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, must meet the following
>   requirements in order to avoid undefined behavior:
>
> 1. All commands that use this buffer object have finished execution before the read command begins execution
> 2. The buffer object is not mapped
> 3. The buffer object is not used by any command-queue until the read command has finished execution

So, to clarify my question, I split it in two:

1. if I create a buffer using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag, can I assume the OpenCL implementation will write to device cache when necessary, so I can *always* avoid to `enqueueWriteBuffer()`?
2. if I call `event.wait()` after launching a kernel, can I *always* avoid to `enqueueReadBuffer()` to access computed data on a buffer created with flag CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR?

Maybe I am overthinking about it, but even if the description of the flag is clear about the fact that the host memory will be used to store the data, it is not clear (or I did not find where it is cleared) about when data is available and if the read/write is always implicit.

Comment: I think this is a VERY good question, because the exact behaviour of MAP/UNMAP/READ/WRITE is not properly defined in the standard. For example, nVIDIA guide for pinned memory says: first create a buffer, then a HOST buffer (using ALLOC_HOST_PTR), then create a map of this last buffer. And then perform a clRead() from the normal buffer to the mapped pointer. Is this explained anywhere in the spec?

Comment: I concur, and I think it's RIDICULOUS that an API that has been available this long does not properly define what it's memory operations do. "oh the graphics driver handles this", gee thanks.

To answer your question, I think the answer is "not necessarily". I've never had a consistency problem by using createbuffer with the CL_MEM_HOST_PTR flag, enqueueing a kernel with the setArg(buffer) of that buffer, and then running enqueueReadBuffer after the kernel completes. I think that approach though may lead to some performance issues, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll never have to use enqueueWriteBuffer(), however you have to use enqueueMapBuffer.

See http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf page 89 (it's the same also in 1.1).

The data is available only after you have mapped the object and will again become undefined after you unmap the object. Also this old thread http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6912-Clarify-CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR contains rather useful description.