# Does OpenCL support Direct memory access between the host and the devices?

Tags: opencl, nvidia, xilinx, dma

I am new to OpenCL. If I invoke clEnqueueWriteBuffer or clEnqueueReadBuffer from the host side, will there be DMA transfers from host to the device and device to the host? The devices will be NVIDIA GPU and XILINX FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yes, `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` and `clEnqueueReadBuffer` use DMA for memory transfer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57857059/9178992) explains how OpenCL memory transfers work in great detail.